# How do i rewrite url (deleting 2folders and 1 get parameter) without redirection?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I am trying to redirect pages created dynamically.

My mvc model force me to have this kind of url:
localhost/page/page_id?id=1
localhost: site url
page : controller
page_id : action
id=1 : parameters

I'd like to have this kind of url:
localhost/1
In other words, delete everything except the value of the "id" parameter.
How can i do that?

I already tried some codes, but it redirects me every time.

My current htaccess (root directory):

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^page/(.*)$ /$1 [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^.*$ /index.php [L]
```

I land there when i type http://localhost/page/page_id?id=1 :
http://localhost/page_id/id=1
With error: "Controller doesn't exist", cause of url being redirected.

What did i missed?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Can there be any controller other than `page` or any action other than `page_id`?

Comment: Of course i have a few controllers i'm using. I just need the rewrite url for this specific url

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try these rules:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^(\d+)/?$ page/page_id?id=$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

Comment: The url doesn't change... i have activated apache rewrite module so i don't understand why...

Comment: Ok i didn't understand that... Thanks, and to answer you when i enter `localhost/page/page_id?id=1` it still works but when i enter `localhost/1` i still have a "controller not found error" because my index.php always think that the first parameter in the url is the controller.

Comment: ok `"controller not found error` is actually your `index.php` issue. Inside the `index.php` code form your actual router URI using **`$uri = $_SERVER["REDIRECT_URL"] . '?' . $_SERVER["QUERY_STRING"];`**

Comment: you are a genius... Thank you so much, it works perfectly !